Typst - Add formatting rules to an already formatted raw block
I'm using Typst for my work and I have some code blocks to show. Inside this code blocks, I want to highlight some parts that are important. In order to do this, I'm using two main functions

One is used to make text Bold (I'm not using * Bold * markdown)
One contains a Regex and I'm looking for the bold_function and I apply a formatting rule to make the content of the bold_function bold

When I don't choose any language for formatting the code blocks (add some color to my code), everything is working. But when I want to put some colors by adding a language to the raw function, my custom formatting isn't working.
If I don't use any language when declaring the raw block, it's working well:
` ``
dfir@dfir-mbp ~ % #text_bold[hello]
` ``


But when I add the language details in the raw block, the language formatting is erasing my custom one:
` ``bash
dfir@dfir-mbp ~ % #text_bold[hello]
` ``


This is a part of my code, I'm using a function to do this:
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Bold Function
//------------------------------------------------------------

#let text_bold(body) = {text( weight: "bold", [#body])}

//------------------------------------------------------------
// Raw converter Function
//------------------------------------------------------------

#let raw_converter(body) = {
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // Find all matches with function #text_bold
  //----------------------------------------------------------
 
  let matches_text_bold = body.text.matches(regex("#text_bold\[[^]]+\]{1,10}"))

  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // Adding the rules
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  show raw.where(): show_rule => {
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the #text_bold rule
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    for it in range(matches_text_bold.len()) {
      // Creating the value inside the #text_bold function
      let text_value = matches_text_bold.at(it).text.replace("#text_bold[","").replace("]","")
      show_rule = {
        // Remove the function to only keep the text inside
        show matches_text_bold.at(it).text: text_bold(text_value)
        show_rule
      }
    }
    show_rule
  }
  
  body
}

#let terminalbox(
  title: "",
  body_box,
) = {
      [... Creating the header of the Box ...]
      //------------------------------------------------------
      //  Body of the Box
      //------------------------------------------------------
      rect(
        width: 100%, 
        radius: (bottom-right: 6pt, bottom-left: 6pt),
        fill: body_color
        inset: (y: 8pt, x: 5pt),
        stroke: (top: 0.8pt + line_color)
        text(
          box_text_size, 
          raw_converter(body_box),
          fill: box_text_color, 
          font: box_text_type,
        ),
      ),
    )
  )
}

#terminalbox(title-bash: "Terminal",
` ` `bash
dfir@dfir-mbp ~ % #text_bold[hello]
` ` `)

